# psql is not working for one specific user

Tags: postgresql

I want to use psql, it works for every user but one.
What config could be wrong ?

It works 1/2:

```
[root]$ psql
psql (13.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

It works 2/2:

```
[postgres]$ psql
psql (13.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

It does not work:

```
[simple_user]# psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Reinstalling postgres does not change anything.

Comment: Looks weird. You could start by editing the questions and telling us what your operating system is and how exactly you installed PostgreSQL.

Comment: Currently I don't know how to phrase the question. Ok I update the post

Comment: Feel like the location of your postgres install was at root, instead of at user level which is why you need sudo to carry out requests? Sorry if this is a wild goosechase.

Comment: It looks like you have more than one `psql` installed with different compiled-in defaults (or they are wrappers which alter the default behavior) , and different OS users find different versions in their path.  What a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user had `PGHOST` exported variable, while other users didn't have.